# Return Datagrams from RawDatagramSocket (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, udp, broadcast

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327927/dart-send-an-udp-broadcast) described how print all Datagrams when sending a broadcast UDP packet. But how to receive a list of them?
I'm try this

```
List<Datagram> list = [];
...
socket.listen(event) {
list.add(socket.receive());
}
...
return list;
```

but this is not works.

```
socket.close();
await socket.toList();
```

save a list of events with just **one** event of closing them.
Is there any way to save a list of datagrams?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to wait

```
List<dynamic> result = [];
InternetAddress destination = InternetAddress("255.255.255.255");
    RawDatagramSocket udp =
        await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port);
    List<int> message = utf8.encode('test');
    udp.broadcastEnabled = true;
    udp.listen((e) {
      Datagram dg = udp.receive();
      if (dg != null) {
        result.add(dg.data);
      {
    });
udp.send(message, destination, port);
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
udp.close();
return result;
```